# Identifying Timestamps

Tags: excel, vba

How does VBA in excel find timestamps?

For example, I am currently trying to delete all rows containing values < a specified date & time. The cells are not strings because it finds an arbitrary date and executes as expected except when the time component is also included.

I have checked and experimented with formatting to no avail. Any hints would be appreciated.

Code:

```
    With wsR
        For r = wsR.Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If wsR.Cells(r, "B") < "18/06/2020 17:00:00" Then
                wsR.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next r
    End With
```

Comment: If a cell contains a date (with or without a time), the value is actually a number.  You can see that by entering a date and time and then using cell formatting to set the cell to General.  The whole part of the number is the number of days since the beginning of 1900 and the decimal part is the seconds in that day (so 00:00:01 1/1/1900 = 1 + 1/86400)  The upshot is that comparing dates with or without times is just comparing numbers.  So we need to see your VBA to understand why it works without the time and doesn't work with the time.

Comment: Always helps to post the code you're trying...

Comment: Thank you, @JerryJeremiah. This is very useful to know. Please see edited Q containing relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, @TimWilliams. Sound point - pls see edited Q for relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
If wsR.Cells(r, "B") < CDate("18/06/2020 17:00:00") Then
```